# Match Word and Alter CSS | JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to black out keywords on webpages that match an array.

```
var array = ["yolo","swag","Justin Bieber"];

$(body).contains(array).css('background-color:black; color:black;');
```

I plan to use this script with greasemonkey to run of every page I load, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't going to work for blacking out words. If a paragraph of text contains any of your words, the CSS styles will be added to the `<p>` tag, not the individual word. You would need to replace all instances of the word with a `<span>` and style that instead

Comment: I got an example working with spans, but I'd have to create a new css rule somehow. http://pastebin.com/4LvyBkJi

Comment: It's a bit rudimentary, but it works. You'll have to consider partial word matches though: http://jsfiddle.net/pPeAP/

Comment: @RGraham - fixed partial word matches with word boundary http://jsfiddle.net/pPeAP/1/

Comment: @SeanJohnson Good update, thanks. Will, You must also consider that your code currently breaks the HTML structure of the page, replacing the html of the first root element.

Comment: @RGraham Yes, it does. Any idea how I could stop this from happening?